# Scylla Upgrade issue from 2.1.x to 2.2.x

Tags: cassandra, upgrade, scylla

While I was upgrading my 3 node Scylla cluster found some mismatch.

I have upgraded one node as procedure described in below link.
https://docs.scylladb.com/upgrade/upgrade-opensource/upgrade-guide-from-2.1-to-2.2/

Once upgrade my one node I have check "nodetool describedcluster" then found "Schema versions" mismatched. upgraded node(2.2.x) is having different "Schema versions" and other 2 nodes(2.1.x) having different "Schema versions"

Like below:-

Schema versions

UUID [xx.xxx.xxx.xx]

UUID [yy.yyy.yyy.yy, zz.zzz.zzz.zz]

After 5 min. I have checked again "nodetool describecluster" found some surprised as below and after 1 hour same also.

Schema versions

UUID [xx.xxx.xxx.xx, yy.yyy.yyy.yy, zz.zzz.zzz.zz]

Is this correct behavior of Scylla?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. When you upgrade a node it is expected that schema versions will differ temporarily but will eventually converge.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. seems in scylla(2.1.x, 2.2.x,3.x) version cassandra version is same 3.0.8